Trying to format imagemagick pango: markup
I have tried these two approaches below with no luck. If I change the first command line and replace pango: with caption: it works, but prints the html markup in the text. When I use pango: it simply fails. I can't seem to find the right command line. Any help would be appreciated.
 $upload = "db.jpg";
 $gravity = "center";
 $overlay_logo = "xaviators_overlay.png";
 $caption_text = strtoupper("PRIVATE JET BOOM: DELIVERIES SURGE IN 2024 AMID HIGH DEMAND AND INDUSTRY CHALLENGES");
 $caption1 = '<span foreground="blue">BLOG: </span>'.$caption_text;
 $caption2 = '<span font="Anton-Regular.ttf" size="1024"><span foreground="blue">BLOG: </span>'.$caption_text.'</span>';

test 1:
exec("convert {$upload} -strip -thumbnail 700x700^ -gravity {$gravity} -extent 700x700 -bordercolor black -border 20 \
-background none -fill white  -size 660x \
-font Anton-Regular.ttf -pointsize 30 -gravity northwest pango:'{$caption1}' -geometry +30+30 -composite \
{$overlay_logo} -gravity southeast -geometry +30+30 -composite out.jpg");

test 2:
exec("convert {$upload} -strip -thumbnail 700x700^ -gravity {$gravity} -extent 700x700 -bordercolor black -border 20 \
-gravity northwest pango:'{$caption2}' -geometry +30+30 -composite \
{$overlay_logo} -gravity southeast -geometry +30+30 -composite out.jpg");

example test img using caption: operator


Try execing identify -version to see if you have pango delegate installed.

I think this is what I have on the server: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-8

Here is the message I got from the data center. It appears to have been installed, but still not working:
I successfully installed Pango:
[root@host pango-1.42.4]# pango-view --version
pango-view (pango) 1.42.3
[root@host pango-1.42.4]#
[root@host pango-1.42.4]# pango-querymodules-64 --version
true (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Please answer my first comment.
